# Launchin chrome in mobile device using webdriverio

Tags: webdriver, webdriver-io, appium-android

I want to launch chrome driver in mobile using webdriverIO. Not able to do so. Any idea how to achieve it?

1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.